# SQL - User Stats table?

Tags: sql

I am working on a multi-choice questions web-app. A user will have to answer 50 to 100 multiple-choice questions. The number of possible answers for each question can differ from 3 to 4 but there is only 1 correct answer.

I would like to create a page stats where the user can come back to the answered questions and see what answer he did select. I am not sure what would be the proper way to do that.

So far I have:

**users table**

[image]

**questions table**
[image]

**answers table**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would organize the `answers` table like this:

[image]

In that way:

- you will not have columns with null values,
- you can have questions with more than 3-4 answers too without adding any extra column
- you can have questions with multiple right answers too

Then, you will need a table, which holds the user's answers:

[image]

Now, you can easily construct a query, which shows the required data.